# Compute the (inverse) Fourier transform of $\cos(k \xi^\alpha)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis

Is it possible to explicitly compute the following integral?
$$\int_{\mathbb R^N} e^{2\pi i x \cdot \xi}\cos(k \, |\xi|^\alpha)\ d \xi$$ where $N \in \mathbb N$ and $\alpha >0$ is a real number? For simplicity, we can also consider the case $N = 1$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Yes.

Comment: Even when $N = 1$ and $\alpha=3$, You may need special functions to describe your integral, such as the [Airy functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function#Definitions). So I am skeptical that we will have an elementary closed form that works for any values of $\alpha$. On the other hand, the cases $\alpha=1$ and $\alpha=2$ can be doable (with the former involving Dirac masses and the latter involving Fresnel integrals).

Comment: when $\alpha\le1$, $\cos |\xi|^{\alpha}$ may be not integrable. However, when $\alpha>1$, we can explictly compute $\int_0^{\infty}\cos (|\xi|^{\alpha})d\xi$.

Comment: When the Fourier transform is a regular distribution, it can be written in closed form in terms of the Fox H-function.